# Building a binary tree from preorder and inorder

Tags: java, binary-tree

I was going through a method to build a binary tree from given preorder and inorder array but I am not able to understand the below step

```
                 preorder_start + offset - inorder_start
                 preorder_start + offset - inorder_start + 1
```

which are passed as arguments in the method `setLeft()` and `setRight()` .It will be a great help if someone can explain me with an example.

```
public BinaryTreeNode buildTreeFromInorderAndPreOrder(int[] preorder, int preorder_start, int preorder_end,
            int[] inorder, int inorder_start, int inorder_end) {
        if (preorder_start > preorder_end || inorder_start > inorder_end)
            return null;
        int data = preorder[preorder_start];                   //We took the starting root data
        BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode(data);        //created a node containing data 
        int offset = inorder_start;                            //offset to point the index of data in inorder array
        while (offset < inorder_end) {                          //while data is not matched in inorder array
            if (inorder[offset] == data)                     
                break;                                         //we get the offset 
            offset++;                                           
        }
        node.setLeft(buildTreeFromInorderAndPreOrder(preorder, preorder_start + 1,
                preorder_start + offset - inorder_start, inorder, inorder_start, offset - 1));
        node.setRight(buildTreeFromInorderAndPreOrder(preorder, preorder_start + offset - inorder_start + 1,
                preorder_end, inorder, offset + 1, inorder_end));
        return node;                                           //finally return the node
    }
```

Comment: Just take an example and track it down. The basic idea is offset in an index into the inorder array where the root is found. You want to count elements between inorder start and that offset and add that count to the preorder array's start to get the end of the left subtree for that root. NOTE: I didn't vote down!

Comment: @Owl thanks your description is helpful.